# UPDATE de informação no banco de dados com PHP utilizando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando realizar um update após enviar os dados pelo formulário mas não consigo, simplesmente não atualiza nada. Verifico os dados pelo $_GET['id'] e os $_POST se estão passando valores e estão tudo ok.

Código:

```
// Verificando se os campos não estão vazios.
if (empty($_POST['nome']) || empty($_POST['quant']) || empty($_POST['valor'])) {
    $msg = "Nenhum campo pode ficar vazio.";
} else {

    // SQL.
    $sql = "UPDATE produto SET nome_produto = :nome, quant_produto = :quant, valor_produto = :valor WHERE id_produto = :id"; 

    // Estabelecendo conexão com o bando e passando os dados com prepare() e via bindValue().
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":id", $_GET['id']);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":nome", $_POST['nome']);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":quant", $_POST['quant']);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":valor", $_POST['valor']);

    // Verificando se deu tudo certo durante a execução.
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    } else {
        $msg = "Erro ao editar produto.";
    }

}
```

Percebi que, ao colocar/setar valores direto no bindValue() funciona, exemplo:

```
    // SQL.
    $sql = "UPDATE produto SET nome_produto = :nome, quant_produto = :quant, valor_produto = :valor WHERE id_produto = :id"; 

    // Estabelecendo conexão com o bando e passando os dados com prepare() e via bindValue().
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":id", 10);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":nome", "Alguma coisa");
    $stmt -> bindValue(":quant", 2000);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":valor", 3.5);

    // Verificando se deu tudo certo durante a execução.
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    } else {
        $msg = "Erro ao editar produto.";
    }
```

Já tentei de tudo, com bindParam(), verifiquei se tinha erro em algo, tentei outras coisas mas deu em nada. Único jeito que funciona é esse mostrado acima.

Comment: Já tentou passar o tipo de dado específico no 3 parâmetro?

Comment: Colocando o PDO::PARAM_INT...
Se for isso já tentei.
Não sei o que está ocorrendo, pior que não dá erro, aí é fods :(

Comment: já tentou associar a variáveis antes e validar o conteúdo (o valor da variável)? por exemplo `$nome = $_POST['nome']` e `$stmt -> bindValue(":nome", $nome);`?

Comment: Acredito que não, mas irei tentar.

Comment: Consegui verificar o que está acontecendo, toda vez que coloco o $_GET['id'] ou uma variável recebendo o mesmo como parâmetro no bindValue() não funciona o update. Agora se eu setar manualmente o número do id, exemplo: 30, ele realiza o update... :s
Acredito que ao clicar no botão para editar quando pego o id via get, reseta o mesmo então não realiza o update no id referente. O que faço agora para ficar com esse valor sem ser resetado quando clicar no botão editar e atualizar a página.

Comment: Fiz umas coisas que resolvi o problema de certo modo, não sei se foi uma gambiarra ou uma opção a parte, kkkkkk. Muito obrigado!